# How do I set margins at runtime?

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro

I have a custom control called MyListView that inherits ListView.

```
songlistMargin = new Thickness(2, 74, 2, Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2 + 18);
playlistMargin = new Thickness(2, Window.Current.Bounds.Height / 2 + 18, 2, 64);

songlistView.Margin = songlistMargin;
playlistView.Margin = playlistMargin;
```

I want songListView to be 74 pixels down when the app starts, and the bottom of songList to be the screensize / 2 + 18 pixels high, but instead it's doing whatever it wants based on the Xaml, and it won't change if the screensize is different.  For example, at 1920x1080 resolution, it's 558 pixels from the bottom, but it's also 558 pixels if the screen resolution is changed.  Same with playListView, but the opposite, I want the top margin to change from 558 depending on the screen resolution.

I think my problem lies in the initialization of the Xaml, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: I also tried binding to songlistMargin and playlistMargin in the xaml, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, was annoying but simple... had to specify the heights of both listviews instead of trying to calculate them with auto.